# How to fetch data from MYSQL database and display it on the application?

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, listview

I want to fetch data from the database using `Json` I tried a lot but the problem i am facing is that the data is not displaying into the screen.

Data is fetching perfectly but it is not displaying into the screen.
stuck in this please help me out..

Here, The Complete Code:

**Order.java**

```
    package com.example.sachin.splashlogin;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Order extends Fragment {

    public Order(){};

    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray ownerObj;
    ListView listview;


    ListViewAdapter3 listadapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    String uid = "0";
    SessionManager session;

    private static String url_visitor = "http://10.0.2.2/portal/fetchinforder.php";
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<String> itemwod = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> itemorder = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> item_remark= new ArrayList<String>();
    //ArrayList<String> o_username= new ArrayList<String>();
    View view;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // don't look at this layout it's just a listView to show how to handle the keyboard
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_order, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Visit");
       // listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvvisit);

        session = new SessionManager(getActivity());
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        uid = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);

        new DownloadJSON().execute();
         return view;
    }


    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
             mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
            // Create an array
            try {
                arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("o_username", uid));
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_visitor, "GET", params);

                int success1 = Integer.parseInt(json.getString("success4"));
                Log.d("success4", json.toString());

                if (success1 == 0) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Not Data Found", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (success1 == 1) {
                    ownerObj = json.getJSONArray("Ordera");
                    // arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    // jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("images");
                    // JSONObject own = ownerObj.getJSONObject(0);
                    // display product data in EditText
                    // uid = own.getString("user_id");

                    for (int i = 0; i < ownerObj.length(); i++) {
                        //   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        jsonobject = ownerObj.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        if (jsonobject.getString("o_username").equalsIgnoreCase(uid)) {


                                itemwod.add(jsonobject.getString("itm_wod"));
                                itemorder.add(jsonobject.getString("itm_order"));
                                item_remark.add(jsonobject.getString("itm_remark"));
                                //   o_username.add(jsonobject.getString("o_username"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                }
                return null;
            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml

            listview = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list123);
            listadapter = new ListViewAdapter3(getActivity(), itemwod,item_remark,itemorder);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(listadapter);
            // Close the progressdialog

            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


}
```

Here,**ListviewAdapter3.java**

```
    package com.example.sachin.splashlogin;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ListViewAdapter3 extends BaseAdapter {
    Context cntx;
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;
    int loader = R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery;


    ArrayList<String> itemwod = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> itemorder = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> item_remark= new ArrayList<String>();
//    ArrayList<String> item_date = new ArrayList<String>();

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();



    public ListViewAdapter3(Context context,
                            ArrayList<String> itm_wod,
                            ArrayList<String> itm_order,
                            ArrayList<String> itm_remark
    ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        cntx = context;


        itemwod = itm_wod;
        itemorder = itm_order;
        item_remark = itm_remark;

        alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do You Want To Call....");


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return item_remark.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return item_remark.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView lvtaskname,lvtaskdetails,lvtaskremark,lvtaskdate;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) cntx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(cntx);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_visit, parent,
                false);


        lvtaskname= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvtaskname);
        lvtaskdetails = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvtaskdetails);
        lvtaskremark = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvtaskremark);
        //lvtaskdate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lvtaskdate);

        lvtaskname.setText(itemwod.get(position));
        lvtaskdetails.setText(itemorder.get(position));
        lvtaskremark.setText(item_remark.get(position));
       //lvtaskdate.setText(item_date.get(position));


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

I created 1 **raw_order.xml**,**activity_order.xml**

Here, **Logcat** in this the data is fetching proper.

```
    09-21 04:49:42.280 8560-9051/com.example.sachin.splashlogin D/Parameters: http://10.0.2.2/portal/fetchinforder.php?o_username=JAYESHBHAI
09-21 04:49:42.633 8560-8570/com.example.sachin.splashlogin W/art: Suspending all threads took: 43.318ms
09-21 04:49:42.683 8560-8574/com.example.sachin.splashlogin I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 16412(1769KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 3% free, 51MB/53MB, paused 18.379ms total 126.498ms
09-21 04:49:42.740 8560-8574/com.example.sachin.splashlogin W/art: Suspending all threads took: 55.554ms
09-21 04:49:42.783 8560-9051/com.example.sachin.splashlogin D/reader: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@d7f027a
09-21 04:49:42.789 8560-9051/com.example.sachin.splashlogin D/P: [o_username=JAYESHBHAI]
09-21 04:49:42.789 8560-9051/com.example.sachin.splashlogin E/Json Object:: {"Ordera":[{"o_parties":"ADCOM ENTERPRISE","o_product":"CTRLV4SWhite","o_remark":"today visit","o_date":"09\/21\/2016","o_username":"JAYESHBHAI"}],"success":1,"o_username":"JAYESHBHAI","date":"09\/21\/2016","success4":1}
09-21 04:49:42.789 8560-9051/com.example.sachin.splashlogin D/success4: {"Ordera":[{"o_parties":"ADCOM ENTERPRISE","o_product":"CTRLV4SWhite","o_remark":"today visit","o_date":"09\/21\/2016","o_username":"JAYESHBHAI"}],"success":1,"o_username":"JAYESHBHAI","date":"09\/21\/2016","success4":1}
09-21 04:49:42.921 8560-8981/com.example.sachin.splashlogin E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa1da1590
```

I don't understand what's wrong in this?? please Help me out from this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
    if (jsonobject.getString("o_username").equalsIgnoreCase(uid)) {
```

Your 'uid' is "0"

```
    String uid = "0";
```

So your if statement returning false.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgot to setText-->

```
    lvtaskname.setText(itemwod.get(position));  -- here you not getName please check  
   //  lvtaskname.setText(itemwod.get(position).getName); --- check this 
    lvtaskdetails.setText(itemorder.get(position));  
    lvtaskremark.setText(item_remark.get(position));  
   //lvtaskdate.setText(item_date.get(position));  


    return convertView;
```